# electric motor feedback thru stereo speakers

Tags: audio

I just installed a JVC radio in my ELECTRIC Atomic cart.  I get really loud motor feedback through the speakers that intensifies with motor speed.  I guess it needs a filter of some type but I have no idea.

Comment: you need something like this...https://www.amazon.com/Radio-Noise-Filter-Suppressor-Stereo/dp/B0763HCF2R

Answer (score 2):

To determine if the interference is coming in through the power wire try this. Remove the power wire and connect it to a separate 12 volt battery, like a booster pack. If the interference continues, a power line filter will not help. Check for ground loops or bad grounding points.